# Reinterpretation of copyrighted work in another medium (film to song)

Tags: copyright, intellectual-property

I've been reading about derivative works and general copyright, but I'm struggling to understand the scope of what is a derivative work.

Allow me to present my situation.

I have written a concept album, it is a retelling of a story previously told in a movie, let's say Robocop.

At no point is the film tile Robocop referenced, the song titles and plot points are designed to be familiar to fans of the movie. A few character names are referenced, and a few lines of dialogue are referenced but the vast majority (99.9%) is original lyrics describing similar scenes and characters.

Is this a derivative work? Does this require a licence? Would it be an infringement? It is essentially a fan homage in song form.

My understanding is that as this doesn't contain any mechanical part of the original movie it is fine. Sorry if this has already been discussed, I couldn't find anything which covered exactly what I want to ask.

**Update:** I though I would add some examples.

[This House Is Not For Sale - Ryan Adams](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_9h_-wXlvVg) is very similar to the story of the film [Beetlejuice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beetlejuice), but at no point directly references it.

[Far Gone - Pictish Trail](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tCjDnqyRp9s) contains the line `She wouldn't stop screaming` which has been acknowledged as being from the film [Fargo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fargo_(film)) and also uses a remixed sample from the [Fargo movie soundtrack](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W4NCC0dUXks) as the hook.

Are these derivative works? Would they be infringing upon IP laws without some kind of licence? And how would they compare to the situation I have outlined?

Answer (score 4):

This is a heavily fact-dependent question. Exactly how and how much your work "evokes" the original will matter.

That said, your belief that "*My understanding is that as this doesn't contain any mechanical part of the original movie it is fine.*" is not at all correct. If your new work is clearly based on the original work, it would be a derivative work. For example, if Shakespear's *Romeo and Juliet* were still in copyright, *West Side story* would have been a derivative work, and would have required permission.

You would do well to consult a lawyer knowledgeable in this specific area, in your specific jurisdiction, as the detailed rules vary by country, although the general principles are pretty much world-wide.